# Does Using Opaque Access Tokens Make My Server Stateful?

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices

I am trying to understand statelessness in restful APIs in the context of authentication. Here's the scenario:

1. The user logs in.
2. The server verifies the username and the password, and generates an opaque access token. It caches some information related to this token - for example, the expiration time, the userId, whether this token was explicitly invalidated before it expired, etc.
3. The token is sent to the client, and the client sends it with every future request.

List item

Fielding's dissertation defines statelessness as:

"...such that each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client."

In my example, the client is sending the token with every request, so the first condition is satisfied. However, my server has a context associated with this session that is stored in the sessions cache.

Does this make my application stateful?

If yes, then is it that true statelessness be achieved only if we are using JWTs? I am pondering upon this as JWTs are quite new, so how were architects building truly stateless services before they were invented?

Answer (score 2):

That's right. If you you maintaining the session you are keeping the state in server which makes the application hard to scale. True stateless applications can be scaled out and any server should be able to handle the request.

JWT is popular way to avoid sessions and everything is encapsulated inside the token for any server to auth/Authorize the request and help us achieve stateless application, they come with their own challenges however OpenID connect is the new way for Auth/Authorization.

Before jwt to make application stateless we used to keep session in DB (or Shared Cache)  , and any server would like to check the session would have to contact DB.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: What you are writing is true. But it all is not relevant for this question. You **don't answer** the question. 1) You are writing about scale ability. But the author **didn't ask** any word about that. 2) You are comparing JWT with OpenID. But the author **didn't ask** about that, neither about OpenID nor about any other alternatives to JWT. 3)  You state that if session data are stored "inside the server. So application is stateless". It means **you don't understand** what is stateless. --> Your answer is **totally misleading**.

Comment: thanks for your comments. The very first line author is stating they want to understand authentication. so i shared everything regarding stateless auth. I don't see where i am comparing JWT with open id ? if you know open id you would know how relevant jwt are. I am still looking for your point 3 and where did i mention saving the session in server makes it stateless?

Comment: 1) The author just explained us the context. He has not asked about scaleability. That's why your 1st paragraph is irrelevant, it would be good to delete it. 2) Yes, my comment about comparison is not correct. It is not a comparison. Nevertheless, the 2nd paragraph is not relevant. "JWT is popular way" - the author does not ask of the purpose of JWT, because he already *uses* it. "is the new way" - first, it is not new. Second, it is not relevant to this question. It woulöd be useful for the question if you delete the 2nd paragraph of you answer.

Comment: 3) "Before that we used to keep session in DB (or Shared Cache) rather inside the server." - It sounds like you consider "used to keep session in DB" as indicator of stateful and  "rather inside the server" an indicator stateless. Your statement "So application is stateless" follows rather inside the server. This means you say "rather inside the server -> that's why it is stateless". If you mean something other, please explain how it is relevant to this question.

Comment: My concern is also to prevent CPU load upon the database. I believe the OP's quote, specifically the digraph "stored context," is the role being played by an RDBMS in this scenario.  The preposition "on" is ambiguous in English, but in a dependency DAG, the server depending on DB is legitimately, "stored context."

Answer (score 0):

**Briefly:** No, such usage of token does not make your application stateful.

**Detailed:** When we talk about stateless/stateful, we consider usually only the data that affect business logic. Business logic does not usually depend on authentication data. For example, a user sends a request that contains all data needed to place some order. Normally creating an order does not depend on when this user has logged in, on his user ID, etc.